How do the various Weight on Wheels (WoW) systems work?
I know that Weight on wheels (WoW) switches indicate whether the weight of an aircraft is resting on its wheels. WoW information reveals whether the aircraft is airborne or on the ground. It also helps to ensure systems are enabled or disabled as befits the aircraft’s situation. Now, my questions are:

How a Weight on Wheel system functions in different jet types such as: Business jet, General Aviation jet
How do A2G and G2A communications depend on the Weights on Wheels system?


Most aircraft have squat switches on the landing gear that are depressed when the air oleo struts reach a certain compression.  I’m not aware of these system interfering with communication equipment, though they may prevent transmission of high energy RF devices such as WX or fire control radars, etc. on the ground for safety reasons.

I won't provide an "answer" as external links to answers are not acceptable and it would be a very long response. But I will provide this link to smartcockpit.com which describes the A320 Landing Gear Systems including the Landing Gear Control Interface Unit (LGCIU). the LGCIU receives inputs from switches and proximity sensors, applies various AND/OR logic to set a large number of discrete outputs. The outputs are used to control various systems functionality based on "In-air" or "on-ground".
